How to fake a secure context for Sveltekit development
On my development system, assume it has the name svkitdev, I am developing a Sveltekit 5 application, which I can run with "npm run dev" and access there via http://localhost:5173. But I also want to access it from browsers on mobile phones or tablets. I set the app up by choosing lucia during npx sv screate (and got oslo, lucia being now "only" a learning platform or so), so there is code setting secure cookies.

Another option is to host your project using a tunnel service like Cloudflare Argo or ngrok. Both support creating ephemeral, hard-to-guess domain names which support HTTPS and will forward connections to your app. These have the advantage that you can connect to your app via any Internet connection, not just the LAN network containing your development machine - for example, you can test your app over a cellular connection, or hand out the link to let other people test your app.

To enable a secure context for your SvelteKit development environment and access it from other devices (e.g., phones or tablets), you need to use HTTPS because "secure" cookies require a secure context in addition to Michael's answer.
Create an SSL certificate for HTTPS. You can use tools like OpenSSL for this. On devices accessing your app, you'll need to trust the self-signed certificate.

To make this work, I need these three steps:
Ports
npm run dev must not only open port 5173 on localhost, but on all addresses. This is done with a change in vite.config.ts:

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
  server: { host: '0.0.0.0', port: 5173 }
});


Browser settings
On the (Chrome) browser of the phone or tablet open
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure 

and set it to the IP address of svkitdev in your network
http://192.168.179.41:5173

Cookies
This requires a hack in the Sveltekit code. In node_modules@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\cookie.js change
/** @type {import('cookie').CookieSerializeOptions} */
const defaults = {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'lax',
    secure: false // MUH url.hostname === 'localhost' && url.protocol === 'http:' ? false : true
};


@Tejzeratul: Sure. The sad fact is, that I don't know yet how to setup HTTPS  in dev mode and also don't want to bother with certificates etc. while still developping. It is a different thing to set up HTTPS on a production server, but my dev machine is not even reachable from the internet.
@nneonneo: Thank you very much! I immediately tried out ngrok, and I immediately ran into CSRF problems: The login form was posted to http://...ngrok-free-app, and the request origin was https:/...ngrok-free-app, so node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js throw a "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden" error. After trying more elegant approaches, I switched off CSRF protection. See above, I added a fourth step.

I use vite-plugin-mkcert for a HTTPS dev server with vite/sveltekit. This plugin handles the certification for you. See npmjs.com/vite-plugin-mkcert
Your vite.config.ts should contain these options:
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        mkcert()
    ],
    server: {
        https: {},
        proxy: {}, // workaround to get dev server working
    }
});

I believe others have given answers regarding the secure cookies, but there is also some documentation for working with mobile devices on the plugin page linked earlier.

One more obstacle: It turns out that IndexedDB is not persistent in an insecure context. And setting #unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure has no effect on this. If I had not learned about ngrok thanks to nneonneo, I would have a real problem now.
